# Selector which apply style to any child elements except for the first

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let we have an HTML code snippet

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="ch1"></div>
    <div id="ch2"></div>
    <div id="ch3"></div>
    ....
    <div id="ch1234"></div>
</div>
```

So how to write a CSS selector which applies a specific styles to any child of `div#parent` except for the `div#ch1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use child and sibling combinators:

```
#parent > div + div
```

Where `div + div` means any `div` following another, which will exclude the first child.

Alternatives include `~` in place of `+`:

```
#parent > div ~ div
```

Or, with the use of CSS3 pseudo-classes (which are not supported in IE8 and older, if that matters to you):

```
#parent > div:nth-child(n+2)
#parent > div:not(#ch1)
```

Comment: This will break if the order of the child element changes

Comment: I think this is the best answer as the plus selector is the most widely supported.

Comment: @Mr.Alien What do you mean? If he just swaps around the divs it will still always not select the first.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Yeah, I'm just following what the title says :/ If `#ch1` can be located anywhere but he still wants to exclude that particular element, then `:not(#ch1)` would certainly be more appropriate.

Comment: @spiel `div + div` will select all the `div` except the first, it doesn't check the `[id=val]` so it kinda breaks if the DOM changes

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ah, that's what you meant. Well yeah, it will no longer select #ch1, but always the first child. The best solution really depends on what Dmitry wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply :

```
#parent div:nth-child(n+2) {
 ...
}
```

this will apply style to every li  except the first no matter how much li you have.

An example http://jsfiddle.net/vzyWq/

btw this is a nice site for these situations http://nth-test.com/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the :not selector:

```
#parent :not(#ch1) {
  styles
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 1):

Without using any `id` as shown in most of the answer.....just using the `parent` id...you can use it this way:

```
#parent div:nth-child(1) ~ div
{
  /*design here*/
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHKnT/)

Target the 1st child onward `div`s of the `parent` and then use the css design using `~` for childs which are not the 1st child!!

Comment: Where the hell have you been today? First time I seen you. Also good job. +1

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a class to which you want to add your changes and define that class

```
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="ch1"></div>
        <div class='myTest' id="ch2"></div>
        <div class='myTest' id="ch3"></div>
        ....
        <div class='myTest' id="ch1234"></div>
    </div>

.myTest{color:red}
```

Hope this helps.